# How can I create this type of table/catalog?

Tags: table

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Hello there! I am a WP Beginner and I am banging my head on how to recreate this table/catalog. I went through a couple of plugins like Ultimate Product catalog, MyListing (paid) and most of the WP Table creators. The point is I want it as close as the one on the screenshot. So before I take any action I would like to hear your opinions. Thank you and have a productive week!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should create custom post type - you can do it with code in functions.php or using a plugin
2. Create basic page template to loop through new post type
3. Add custom fields to store extra data as in tour screenshot. I usually use acf plugin for it
4. Fine tune your new page template with the display of custom fields.

That’s it

Comment: Thank you very much on the fast response! I will dig into that!

Comment: To be able to filter through those custom fields, I need to fine tune the page. Did I understand correct? My idea is to have maximum 2 or 3 filters like age and price. Thank you again for your time Alex! Much appreciated!

Comment: As you need filter you need to create custom post type with taxonomies (you can add multiple taxonomies to one post type) - see the tutorial in here https://crunchify.com/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-post-type-cpt-and-taxonomy-hello-world-tutorial-tips-and-tricks/. After you will be able to use these taxonomies as filters